# Get variable "picture" from json GraphRequest Facebook SDK using gson

Tags: java, android, json, facebook, android-studio

I've made login and handle the accesstoken, also get the response from GraphResponse FacebookSDK.
What I would like to achieve is get the data "picture" from json response.

how could i possibly parse it using gson? and or what is the possible Pojo class that I can actually made to get the data result?

Here is my Json Response from GraphResponse.

```
{
  "albums": {
    "data": [
      {
        "photos": {
          "data": [
            {
              "picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/"
            },
            {
              "picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/"
            },
            {
              "picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/",
              "id": "1020051059"
            }
          ],
          "paging": {
            "cursors": {
              "before": "MTAyMODNzAzNDUZD",
              "after": "MTAy1M5ODkwNTkZD"
            }
          }
        },
        "id": "10200419072"
      },
      {
        "photos": {
          "data": [
            {
              "picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/",
              "id": "10248202764"
            }
          ],
          "paging": {
            "cursors": {
              "before": "MTAyMDNzQUyMDI3NjQZD",
              "after": "AyMDU5NzjUyMDI3NjQZD"
            }
          }
        },
        "id": "1020597122762"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "MTAyMDA1QE1MDkwNzIZD",
        "after": "MTAyMDNzQ4UxMjI3NjIZD"
      },
      "next": "https://scontent.xx.net/"
    }
  },
  "id": "102088470922"
}
```

Here is my MainActivity.class

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        initLogin();
    }

    private void initLogin(){
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // App code

                        USER_TOKEN = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
                        info.setText("Access Token " + USER_TOKEN);
                        initGraph();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                        info.setText("Login attempt canceled.");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                        info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
                    }
                });
    }

    private void initGraph() {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        // Insert your code here
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject();

                        try {
                            Log.i(TAG,jsonObject.getString("albums"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.i(TAG, "-------------------------");
                    }
                });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "albums.limit(2){photos{picture}}");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Like i said, I've successfully get the response, but I am struggling, to figure out how to parse it (if it possible, using gson). OR, is it possible to catch the "GraphResponse response", using Http Client like "Retrofit or OKHTTP?".

So far, I've been able to do GET method using Retrofit for Api Call movie database, like TMDB  based from this [url](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/)

Comment: Create your pojo class using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ for your graph api response.

Answer (score 0):

I successfuly get the album cover an total photos in album also the album name.. Please visit my [github](https://github.com/dunprek/facebook/tree/album/app/src/main)